# github for windows, cloned repos don't put in github tab

Tags: github-for-windows

Situation: I've cloned some repos from github, and I'm expecting them to be put in github tab, but they are only available in local repos tab. Their names still contain creators names ( someUser/someRepo )
Tried to clone with bash/clone to desktop button/drag&drop, and get expected same result.

link: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2912/uz4b.jpg

What I want: Cloned repos must be shown in github tab, separated by authors, with  nice avatars and so on. (as it is shown on of website)

What I get: Cloned repos put in local repositories tab and messed up with oser dozens of local repos witch I create every 5 minutes for every task i need.

os winxp, app version 1.0.56.0
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to github support, "Currently the 'github' tab only shows repositories that are under your account or under an organization that you belong to."

Maybe requested feature will be added later